# Passing variables from mutation to query

Tags: graphql, hasura

I have a GraphQL mutation that creates an item and returns the data that's created. I need to pass some of the created fields into a query. Is this possible? This is almost working but I can't figure out how to get the data between the mutation and the query:

```
mutation {
    createToken(
        input: { tokenname: "my token", tokendescription: "my valuable token" }
    ) {
        id
        randomdata
    }
  insert__helloworld_article(objects: [{randomdata: "Hello" , author_id: 1}]) {
    returning {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

So my problem is getting "randomdata" from the mutation to insert into the helloworld_article

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to use the return value in the same mutation with GraphQL, however if those objects have a relationship you could do a [nested insert](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/databases/postgres/mutations/insert.html#insert-an-object-along-with-its-related-objects-through-relationships).